# State of checkboxes changed after hide numeric keyboard in a custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a custom ListView with some TextViews, EditTexts and a checkbox that represents a item of a shopping list. When I type values in the value EditText, I check the checkbox and a Toast show me the sum of the values multiplied by their respective quantities and when all checkboxes of all items are checked a dialog show me the total value of the shopping list. My problem is that when the numeric keyboard is hidden after I enter values the checkboxes lost their checked states. What could be the problem?

This is some part of the code of my getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = contexto.getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = contexto.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.texto = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescricao);
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkProduto);
        holder.edtValor = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtValor);
        holder.edtQtde = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantidade);
        holder.btnMenos = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnMenos);
        holder.btnMais = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnMais);
        //holder.btnExcluir = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnExcluir);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    editor = sharedPrefs.edit();

    holder.posicao = position;
    holder.texto.setText(getItem(position).getTexto());     

    if(getItem(position).getValor() > 0)
        holder.edtValor.setText(Double.toString(getItem(position).getValor()));
    else
        holder.edtValor.setText("");

    holder.edtValor.setTag(new LinhaItemTag(getItem(position), position));  
    holder.edtValor.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcherValor(holder));       

    if(quantidades[position] > 0)
        holder.edtQtde.setText(Integer.toString(quantidades[position]));
    else
        holder.edtQtde.setText("");

    holder.edtQtde.setTag(new LinhaItemTag(getItem(position), position));   
    holder.edtQtde.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcherQuantidade(holder));

    holder.btnMenos.setTag(new LinhaItemTag(getItem(position), position));  
    holder.btnMais.setTag(new LinhaItemTag(getItem(position), position));
    //holder.btnExcluir.setTag(new LinhaItemTag(getItem(position), position));


    holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    //holder.checkbox.setChecked(getItem(position).Selecionado());
    getItem(position).setSelecionado(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("CheckValue"+position, false));
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(getItem(position).Selecionado());
    holder.checkbox.setTag(new LinhaItemTag(getItem(position), position));

    holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            LinhaItemTag elemento = (LinhaItemTag) buttonView.getTag();
            elemento.item.setSelecionado(isChecked);        
            editor.putBoolean("CheckValue"+position, isChecked);
            editor.commit();

            if (isChecked) {
                pegos[elemento.position] = true;                    
            } else {
                pegos[elemento.position] = false;               
            }

            String vlrTotal = calculaTotal();

            boolean checados = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
                if (!pegos[i]) {
                    checados = false;
                    break;
                }
            }           
            if (checados) {             
                mostraDlgFinaliza();                                        
            }
            else if(getItem(elemento.position).Selecionado())
            {
                Toast.makeText(contexto, "R$ " + vlrTotal, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

//Other piece of code

return convertView;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use setOnClickListener() Instead of setOnCheckChangedListener for Android CheckBoxes

Instead of `setOnCheckChangedListener()`, you should use `setOnClickListener()` and determine the checked setting via `holder.checkbox.isChecked()`.

**Example**:

```
holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        final boolean isChecked = holder.checkBox.isChecked();
        // Do something here.
    }
});
```

The `CheckBox` changed listener is not valid because the individual `CheckBox` objects are constantly being recycled and reset for various reasons such as `ListView/GridView` scroll or screen redraw due to orientation/keyboard change. Each `CheckBox` can show up in various positions as they go in and out of view. That is why you must set the check value every time in `getView()` and you must respond to clicks.

Otherwise, if you respond only to checked changes, you will receive `checkChanged` callbacks at unexpected times as the `CheckBox` are recycled and sometimes you will not receive the callback at all if the checked states in cells being swapped have the same check setting.